# Regex: match after colon in H1 tag?

Tags: regex

I hope its okay I ask this, I searched around stackoverflow and found similair questions but no solutions worked for me.

I have HTML like this:
`<h1>Beatles: A Hard Days Night</h1>` now I would like a regex to match everything AFTER the colon. So `A Hard Days Night` in this case.

This is what I tried:

```
$pattern = "/<h1>\:(.*)<\/h1>/";
```

But this just outputs an empty array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following regex should match that:

```
<h1>[^:]+:\s+([^<]+)
```

PowerShell test:

```
PS> '<h1>Beatles: A Hard Days Night</h1>' -match '<h1>[^:]+:\s+([^<]+)'; $Matches
True

Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              A Hard Days Night
0                              <h1>Beatles: A Hard Days Night
```

A little explanation:

```
<h1>    # match literal <h1>
[^:]+   # match everything *before* the colon (which in this case
        # shouldn't include a colon itself; if it does, then use .*)
:       # Literal colon
\s+     # Arbitrary amount of whitespace
([^<]+) # Put everything up to the next < into a capturing group.
```